# how to pass auto generated input to an api function in laravel

Tags: api, input

i have a web system whereby the input fields are autogenerated and saved in the database.i want to push the input data to an api function and have been able to push some of the inputs.i have which is autogenerated but am unable to push it.its the systemid.here is the code that generates it

```
  $SystemID        = new SystemID('product');
  //the new SystemID('product'); autogenerates the the systemid which is saved in the product table
  $product         = new product();
  $product->systemid = $SystemID;
  $product->save();
```

i have tried this code in the api function of the controller but it shows an error **systemid cannot be null**

```
$productdetails=new Product;
$productdetails->systemid =$request->systemid;
```

also i have a SystemID class in the in the other apiendpoint web system.
how can i pass the autogenerated systemid to the controller in the api?

on dd(SystemID); i get this

````
-type: "03"
-id: 1509
-invalid: false
-allowed_type: array:52 [
  "company" => array:2 [
    0 => "company_seq"
    1 => "01"
  ]
  "individual" => array:2 [
    0 => "individual_seq"
    1 => "02"
  ]
  "product" => array:2 [
    0 => "product_seq"
    1 => "03"
  ]
  "location" => array:2 [
    0 => "location_seq"
    1 => "04"
  ]
  "terminal" => array:2 [
    0 => "terminal_seq"
    1 => "05"
  ]
  "counter" => array:2 [
    0 => "counter_seq"
    1 => "07"
  ]
  "voucherlist" => array:2 [
    0 => "voucher_seq"
    1 => "08"
  ]
  "takeaway" => array:2 [
    0 => "takeaway_seq"
    1 => "09"
  ]
  "stockreport" => array:2 [
    0 => "stockreport_seq"
    1 => "11"
  ]
  "wastage" => array:2 [
    0 => "wastage_seq"
    1 => "12"
  ]
  "rack" => array:2 [
    0 => "rack_seq"
    1 => "13"
  ]
  "promo" => array:2 [
    0 => "promo_seq"
    1 => "14"
  ]
  "member" => array:2 [
    0 => "member_seq"
    1 => "15"
  ]
  "loyaltypts" => array:2 [
    0 => "loyaltypts_seq"
    1 => "16"
  ]
  "membershipmts" => array:2 [
    0 => "membershipmts_seq"
    1 => "17"
  ]
  "franchise" => array:2 [
    0 => "franchise_seq"
    1 => "18"
  ]
  "og_tank" => array:2 [
    0 => "ogtank_seq"
    1 => "19"
  ]
  "calibration" => array:2 [
    0 => "calibration_seq"
    1 => "20"
  ]
  "controller" => array:2 [
    0 => "controller_seq"
    1 => "21"
  ]
  "pump" => array:2 [
    0 => "pump_seq"
    1 => "22"
  ]
  "invoice" => array:2 [
    0 => "invoice_seq"
    1 => "23"
  ]
  "salesorder" => array:2 [
    0 => "salesorder_seq"
    1 => "24"
  ]
  "trackingreport" => array:2 [
    0 => "trackingreport_seq"
    1 => "25"
  ]
  "stocktake" => array:2 [
    0 => "stocktake_seq"
    1 => "26"
  ]
  "refund" => array:2 [
    0 => "refund_seq"
    1 => "27"
  ]
  "cmr" => array:2 [
    0 => "cmr_seq"
    1 => "28"
  ]
  "platform" => array:2 [
    0 => "platform_seq"
    1 => "29"
  ]
  "creditnote" => array:2 [
    0 => "creditnote_seq"
    1 => "30"
  ]
  "debitnote" => array:2 [
    0 => "debitnote_seq"
    1 => "31"
  ]
  "agent" => array:2 [
    0 => "agent_seq"
    1 => "32"
  ]
  "comm_company" => array:2 [
    0 => "comm_company_seq"
    1 => "32"
  ]
  "pts_prd_redemption" => array:2 [
    0 => "pts_prd_redemption_seq"
    1 => "33"
  ]
  "ec_buyer" => array:2 [
    0 => "ec_buyer_seq"
    1 => "34"
  ]
  "ec_merchant" => array:2 [
    0 => "ec_merchant_seq"
    1 => "35"
  ]
  "ec_receipt" => array:2 [
    0 => "ec_receipt_seq"
    1 => "36"
  ]
  "csr" => array:2 [
    0 => "csr_seq"
    1 => "37"
  ]
  "cpcr" => array:2 [
    0 => "cpcr_seq"
    1 => "38"
  ]
  "projmgmt" => array:2 [
    0 => "projmgmt_seq"
    1 => "39"
  ]
  "projmgmt_job" => array:2 [
    0 => "projmgmtjob_seq"
    1 => "40"
  ]
  "asset" => array:2 [
    0 => "asset_seq"
    1 => "47"
  ]
  "hcap_staff" => array:2 [
    0 => "hcap_staff_seq"
    1 => "42"
  ]
  "pjobproduct" => array:2 [
    0 => "pjobproduct_seq"
    1 => "43"
  ]
  "ext_stockreport" => array:2 [
    0 => "ext_stockreport_seq"
    1 => "44"
  ]
  "purchaseorder" => array:2 [
    0 => "purchaseorder_seq"
    1 => "45"
  ]
  "deliveryorder" => array:2 [
    0 => "deliveryorder_seq"
    1 => "46"
  ]
  "vehicle" => array:2 [
    0 => "vehicle_seq"
    1 => "48"
  ]
  "atg" => array:2 [
    0 => "atg_seq"
    1 => "49"
  ]
  "converter" => array:2 [
    0 => "converter_seq"
    1 => "50"
  ]
  "converterport" => array:2 [
    0 => "converterport_seq"
    1 => "51"
  ]
  "arpayment" => array:2 [
    0 => "arpayment_seq"
    1 => "52"
  ]
  "carparklot" => array:2 [
    0 => "carparklot_seq"
    1 => "54"
  ]
  "authorize" => array:2 [
    0 => "authorize_seq"
    1 => "55"
  ]
]
-global_platform: 1
}```
````

Comment: the systemid is created and saved in the products table perfectly.i have tested that and its working but am unable to get it and push it t the api

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the SystemID first, here you only created an object SystemID so it doesn't have an id.

```
  $SystemID        = new SystemID('product');
  $SystemID->save();
  $product         = new product();
  $product->systemid = $SystemID;
  $product->save();
```

Comment: am getting an error "Call to undefined method App\Classes\SystemID::save()" when i try to run the code

Comment: oh, maybe it's because you try to assign an object to an id in :

$product->systemid = $SystemID;


What does your $SystemID look like ?
It should maybe be:

$product->systemid = $SystemID->id;

Comment: on my web system the systemid is generated and being saved to the database,i want to push the saved systemid to the api

Comment: Can you show what the SystemID looks like ?
Like with :
dd($SystemID);

I think the problem is the assignation :
$product->systemid = $SystemID;
as $product->systemid must got a number and $SystemID is an object, it should look like:
$product->systemid = $SystemID->value;
or
$product->systemid = $SystemID->id;

Comment: i have edited the question again and have added the SystemID class